# Plotting species and amount against over a certain distance

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

So first of all I am very very new to R. I have walked 50m and counting species I have seen in 5m intervals. Each individual has been given a value in meters according to where they were found. Now I am trying to plot the number of species found against the distance but in the plot, I want to create individual colored dots grouped by species recorded as well.

First, I counted how many times each species was recorded

```
count <- intidal %>%  
  count(Animal)
```

And i tried creating the plot with:

```
ggplot(intidal, aes(x=Distance, y=intidal %>% count(Animal))) + 
  geom_point(aes(col=Animal)) + 
  geom_smooth(method="loess", se=F) + xlim(c(0, 0.1)) + ylim(c(0, 500000)) + 
  labs(title="Species along line transect", y="Number of species", x="Distance")
```

But I get the error code:

> "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data
> (512)" and I am just not sure how to work around this, or if anyone
> has tips to what I should do differently.

[How my data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph5tv.png)

Comment: Can you post some data? What does intidal contain?

Comment: Contains 2 columns, 1 for distance and 1 for which species is found. Has a total of 512 rows. So essentially it tells you at which distance a species was found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

intidal %>%  
  count(Animal, Distance) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Distance, y= n)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col=Animal)) + 
  geom_smooth(method="loess", se=F) +
  labs(title="Species along line transect", y="Number of species", x="Distance")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the count to increase over the distance...

Assuming the data is ordered by distance. Group by each Animal and count the occurrences of each Animal. Then group by Animal and Distance and get the highest Count of each, the Count of each Animal at each Distance increment.

```r
library(tidyverse)

intidal <- intidal %>%
  group_by(Animal) %>%
  mutate(Count = 1:n()) %>% 
  group_by(Animal, Distance) %>% 
  top_n(1, Count)
```

And if you want different lines for each Animal...

```r
intidal %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x = Distance, y = Count, colour = Animal)) +
    geom_point() + 
    geom_line() +
  labs(title = "Animal", y = "Count of Animal", x = "Distance")
```

[image: Animals over Distance]

Maybe it would be good to add data for each animal at distance increments where no animals were observed.